# Генерация картинки с помощью php

Tags: php, wordpress

Появилась необходимость на WordPress в page динамически отдавать картинку. Т.е. где-то у нас есть ссылка `<img src="mysite.domain/image?params"/>` и вот как раз при обращении на адрес mysite.domain/image?params должна отдаваться одна из заранее подготовленных картинок, которые лежат в корне шаблона.

Comment: и проблема ваша в чем заключается?

Comment: уже ни в чем, разобрался, изначально было что через echo ничего не отображалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге разобрался как все правильно сделать: довольно тривиальный скрипт

```
$im = imgUrl;
header('content-type: image/svg+xml'); 
readfile("$im");
```